# Assosiated function that returns an element of an assosiated const array?

Tags: rust, lifetime, associated-const

I illustrate this general question with an example: I have a `Color`-Struct which holds three `u8`s (Red, Green, Blue). `Color` has an assosiated constant `Color::PREDEFINED` with some predefined colors. I need an assosiated function `Color::pick_one` returning one of these predefined colors, depending on a given parameter:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Color (u8, u8, u8);
impl Color {
    const PREDEFINED: [Color; 3] = [
        Color(90, 250, 10),
        Color(120, 10, 10),
        Color(40, 10, 200)
    ];
    pub fn pick_one (param: i32) -> Color {
        let index = // do some math with `param`.
        Color::PREDEFINED[index]
    }
    pub fn to_string (&self) -> String {
        format!("rgb({}, {}, {})", self.0, self.1, self.2)
    }
}
```

Now this obviously doesn't work since `pick_one` returns a `Color` from `PREDEFINED`, but we `cannot move out of type [Color; 3], a non-copy array`.

A solution could be to clone the returned Color:

```rust
Color::PREDEFINED[index].clone()
```

but is this good performance?

I would also be fine with `pick_one` returning a `&Color` instead of a `Color`, but:

```rust
pub fn pick_one (param: i32) -> &Color {
    let index = // do some math with `param`.
    &Color::PREDEFINED[index]
}
```

gives:

```
missing lifetime specifier
this function's return type contains a borrowed value, but there is no value for it to be borrowed from
consider using the `'static` lifetime: `'static `
```

Now, is this the right place to use `'static`?

I find it actually confusing that

```rust
pub fn pick_one (&self, param: i32) -> &Color {
    let index = // do some math with `param`.
    &Color::PREDEFINED[index]
}
```

works quite well – this looks a bit like the [3rd lifetime elision rule](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-elision), right? But isn't the idea of this rule: A methos can't be called after `self` was dropped, thus, returned references to fields of `self` is always valid? But this isn't the point here, since `PREDEFINED` is not a field of `self`, but assosiated to `Color` itself, making references to `PREDEFINED` be valid as long as `Color` exists (i.e. always). And making `pick_one` a method is actually pointless, since always calling `Color(0, 0, 0).pick_one(12)` is technically possible, but doesn't make sense from a semantic point of view.

Now, what is the best way to implement such an assosiated function returning a value from an assosiated constant?

Comment: Any reason not to make `Color` implement `Copy`, given that it's absolutely tiny?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is clone good for performance?

Copying 3 bytes is extremely cheap. This will almost always be more performant than making a reference. This cheapness is why [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) exists, and you should use it here:

```rs
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct Color (u8, u8, u8);
```

```rs
pub fn pick_one (param: i32) -> Color {
    let index = ...;
    Color::PREDEFINED[index]
}
```

The general rule is to derive `Copy` whenever possible.

> Is this the right place to use `'static`?

Yes. If you're returning a reference, and its lifetime doesn't belong to one of the parameters, it's pretty much always `'static`.

```rs
pub fn pick_one (param: i32) -> &'static Color {
```

> `pick_one (&self, param: i32) -> &Color`

This one only makes sense if you want to reserve the ability of producing the return from `self` in a future version without breaking your API. However, this also only makes sense for non-`Copy` types, so even if you produce the return from `self`, it should still be a straight `Color` with no reference.

---

Side note: when you have a tuple of all the same type, consider doing `struct Color([u8; 3])`. This is equivalent in memory representation and gives you all the methods on `array`, helping to reduce code duplication, like:

```rs
let c = Color([10, 10, 10]);
let half_c = Color(c.0.map(|n| n / 2));
```

Comment: One could argue that in extremely perf-sensitive code, it is better to return a reference and let the caller decide whether to copy.

Comment: What ist the general rule when `Copy` or `clone()` is better than references? For example, in a performance-sensitive context with a much larger struct... Is it as simple as: the reference is 64 bit, so when the struct ist smaller than this, use `Copy`?

Comment: @ferdi2003 It depends. But since there isn't much between "should be copied" and "should be allocated on the heap", the idiomatic rust rule is to always copy `Copy` types and always reference `Clone` types, when possible. A lot of the time, compiler optimization will eliminate copies and references anyway. There's also a soft rule that you shouldn't write unidiomatic or unsafe code for performance reasons unless you have benchmarked the specific usage, in which case it's obvious which one is better.